# Suppose f is a twice differentiable function with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$. Then show that $|f''(x)| > 4$ for some $x$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Any help would​ be appreciated. 
My initial attempts were using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem first between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to show that $f'(t)=1$ for some $t$ in $(0,1)$. 
Now applying LMV between $f'(t)$ and $f'(0)$, and $f'(t)$ and $f'(1)$ I could prove it if t lies in either $(0,1/4]$ or in $[3/4,1)$.
Don't really know where to go next.

Comment: Mathjax formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Under the given conditions the claim isn't true.

Comment: @md2perpe  How can you say that?

Comment: Take $f(x) = 2x^2$ when $x \in [0, \frac12]$ and $f(x) = 1-2x^2$ when $x \in (\frac12, 1]$. This function satisfies the conditions but not the claim.

Comment: Isn't your function not differentiable?

Comment: Oh, you're partly right. It's once differentiable but not twice. I thought that it was twice differentiable but that $f''$ just wasn't continuous. Then my counter example falls.